# Fedora 16 install does not fully shutdown

Tags: fedora, shutdown

I did a fresh install (not upgrade) of Fedora 16 shortly after it came out. However I've never been able to have it fully shutdown. When you select it I can see it try to shutdown, but it doesn't finish

I turned off quiet booting so I see mostly what Linux is trying to do. IIRC usually the last line is something about shutting down the live image, after that it just hangs.

Is there anything I can do to get Fedora to shutdown correctly? Note that I'm on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 Laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you had updated all the patches, i used to have this issue until gotten kernel 3.1.2-1 working now.

Comment: Hmm, just updated and tested, seems to of been fixed. Thanks for pointing this out